# Modify SQL Server UDT - which exists in Production Environment

Tags: sql-server-2012, user-defined-types

We have three environments Dev/QA/Prod,

If we are modifying any db object, which is already in production, then we rename the object by adding "_01" and then add the old object name to a file "Unused Objects" — to be deleted later. 
For example, if we alter any procedure to add a new parameter which is not null,then we follow this process to achieve backward compatibility.
We use SQL DACPAC to publish the DB changes to server. At least we use it on QA.

Now if we are modifying an UDT which exists in production and add a new nullable column to it.  This UDT is in production and used by some of the procs.

So is it required to rename the UDT as "_01" and follow the usual process?
**How does the SQL Dacpac handle the alteration of UDT?** as there is no alter UDT statement available.
Will it affect any existing procs?

Old UDT:

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestUDT] AS TABLE 
    (
        [Column1]               [int]           NOT NULL,
        [Column2]               [int]           NOT NULL,
    )
```

New UDT:

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestUDT] AS TABLE 
    (
        [Column1]               [int]           NOT NULL,
        [Column2]               [int]           NOT NULL,
        [Column3]               [int]           NULL,
    )
```

Comment: We are using UDT in proc as parameter, `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest_Test]
    @UserId INT ,
    @TestUDT dbo.[TestUDT] READONLY ,`

Comment: Also checked the link [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-]us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx